# Searching data using Youtube API

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

Extremely new at this, but wanted to try to build something. Decided on a simple landing page that would assist in pulling Youtube videos. Got my API key and got to building. Ran into a few issues. Found out that it can't call from a local HTML file, so worked out another way to test, but now I have another issue.

I have the following code set to run when a button is pressed, submitting the text in form as the variable topic.

```
function search() {
var hdi = "how do i ";
var request = gapi.client.youtube.search.list({
    part: 'id',
    q: hdi + topic,
});
request.execute(onSearchResponse);
};


function onSearchResponse(response){
var responseString = JSON.stringify(response, " ", 2);
console.log(responseString);
}
```

But I cannot seem to get the response I'm looking for. The JSON data I get seems to correspond to medley of search engines (Yahoo, duck duck go, ect) instead, not the JSON data for the YouTube search.

Here is a CodePen, if that assists more. I have some code commented out that I'm waiting to work on until I get this part implemented. Thanks for any help you can give me!

https://codepen.io/billsobill/pen/OvxNON

Comment: The CodePen link is missing

Comment: Probably need to set type: video. Look through parameters of https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#type.

Comment: The cool version of CodePen is called StackSnippets, you can introduce the magic by hitting `<>` while [edit]ing

Comment: Ah, sorry about the forgotten CodePen link.
I'll review the parameters and see what I can dig up, also.